# Can't get incoming call event

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to implement getting incoming call events in background and foreground. So I've created BroadcastReceiver for that purpose, but onReceive() method doesn't fired after I got/getting/finished incoming call. 
I've tryed tons of tutorial, but nothing helped me:(

Please help.

**MANIFEST**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="yakiv.bondar.dev.incomeoutcomecalltest">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".IncomingCall"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

**Broadcast receiver**

```
public class IncomingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("tag", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");
    MyPhoneStateListener phoneListener=new MyPhoneStateListener();
    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}

public class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state,String incomingNumber){
        switch(state){
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                Log.d("tag", "IDLE");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d("tag", "OFFHOOK");
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d("tag", "RINGING");
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to register your receiver in your activity

Comment: sripad is right , you have to register the receiver

Comment: @SripadRaj i've registered it in Manifest.xml? Is it not enough?

Comment: You have just declared in your manifest, but if you want your broadcast listener to listen something you have to register it in your activity.

Comment: @SripadRaj I've added: String BROADCAST = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"; 
 IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST); IncomingCall receiver = new IncomingCall(); registerReceiver(receiver , intentFilter); but onReceive() still not fired.

Comment: follow @user6709464 answer.

Comment: @SripadRaj Just tryed as it shown in the answer. Didn't help:(

Comment: Are you running this on android 6.0? If yes, you have to handle permissions at runtime.

Comment: @SripadRaj Permission was the point. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed calling `registerReciever(intent,intentFilter)` in your Activity. Register your activity in `onResume()` and call `unregisterReciever(intent)` in your `onPause()` method.

**NOTE:**

Also check if you have given appropriate permissions in your manifest and also note that even if you have declared your required permissions you have to handle certain permissions in runtime in **Android 6.0** and above. Check [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) for handling permissions at runtime for Marshmallow and above.

Answer (score 0):

In MainActivity:

```
    IncomingCall mBroadcastReceiver = new IncomingCall();
```

In onResume:

```
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    this.registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver , filter);
```

In onPause:

```
    this.unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver );
```

Comment: I've added: String BROADCAST = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"; IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(BROADCAST);
        IncomingCall receiver = new IncomingCall();
        registerReceiver(receiver , intentFilter); but onReceive() still not fired.

Comment: Tryed that. Doesn't help:(

Answer (score -1):

1) Make sure your app has the permissions to READ_PHONE_STATE

2) you do not need to registerReceiver( BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter) since you have it in your Manifest

3)MAke sure the notification are turned on for your App (Check Settings--> Application Manager --> your app --> Notifications)

4) I would try testing without "break" in the switch statements

5) try with Toast instead of Log. Toast.makeText( Context, String , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();